# Suds accumulating at the base of a tree

Tags: landscaping

Today is cool and rainy and I noticed suds accumulating at the base of a tree. They seem to be oozing out of the tree (on one side only) and dripping down from a height of about four feet. There is some sort of lichen (?) growing on this side of the tree, but I don't see the same suds on nearby trees, some of which have the same lichen growing. Any idea what this is, and whether I need to take action?

Update: Today it's not raining and the "suds" are totally gone, so it was definitely something caused or made visible by the rain.

[image]

Comment: Apologies if this is off-topic (it seemed to be considered gray area in meta.diy discussions.)

Comment: Do you know what kind of a tree this is?

Comment: I think it's an oak, but the leaves are way out of reach and my tree ID skills are poor so take that with a grain of salt.

Comment: This question may be better suited for the [Gardening and Landscaping](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be [spittlebugs](http://www.essortment.com/all/pinetreesarato_pkg.htm)...

Comment: It's definitely not a pine - would spittlebugs infect other trees? I didn't see any bugs, although that doesn't mean they weren't there...

Comment: I have no idea, I just did a Google search.  :)  Here's another page with some more info: http://en.allexperts.com/q/Plant-Diseases-715/2009/3/Foam-around-trees.htm

Comment: It's weird that it's not an oak tree, but everything else seems to fit.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of Googling, the prevailing theory seems to be that the foam is from rainwater washing over impurities that have collected on the tree trunk. It forms a crude sort of soap and accumulates at the base of the tree.

[Hiker's Blog](http://ramblinghemlock.blogspot.com/2010/09/first-website.html)

[Gardening Website](http://www.walterreeves.com/gardening-q-and-a/pine-bubbles-on-bark/)

[Forestry Forum](http://www.forestryforum.com/board/index.php?topic=36551.0)